# Set the source of Adobe PDF browser plugin to be a byte stream?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, xhtml, acrobat

Is it possible to have the source for an Adobe Plugin to be a PDF byte stream?

If so, how would this be declared in markup?

EDIT 1:
OK, so let me elaborate on this. I have built a site that runs on Azure. The site's back-end is a WCF web service, also on Azure.

One particular functionality of the site has to do with reporting. Once the user selects the type of report they want, a request is made to the service and a byte stream of a pdf file is sent back as a response.

Now, the question is how would the user view the file? Is it possible to set the Adobe Acrobat PDF plugin's document source to be something along the lines of:

```
<OBJECT>
<PARAM src="asdfkjaskflasjdlfkjasd"/> //byte stream
<PARAM mimeType="application/pdf;"/> //stream's mime type
</OBJECT>
```

EDIT 2:

OK, so no-one wants to take a crack at this. However, the only reason I am asking is because it is entirely possible to set the source of an image with the following code:

```
<img class="myImage" img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAAJCAYAAA"/>
```

where everything past the `image/png;base64` represents the byte content of the image encoded as a base64 string.

So is it still possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt the Adobe plugin can be made to fetch PDF data from a `data:` URL.

And even if it is possible in some browsers, you will with 100% certainty not be able to achieve a cross-browser solution this way: `data:` URLs don't work in IE < 8 at all, and are [limited to 32 kilobytes' size 8 and 9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

What speaks against simply serving the byte stream in a separate resource with a PDF content-type?

Comment: The fact that my app needs a secondary azure storage container for the generated pdf files. Storage costs $$$

Comment: @bleepzter there is no way of just passing through the PDF byte data without any HTML around it?

Comment: I can do anything with the pdf stream. Accept save it to a physical disk. Hence the trouble since pdf plugins want a href pointing to a file uri.

Comment: Congrats on a well deserved 100K :)